# SharePoint online search crawling issue

Tags: sharepoint-online, search, office-365

Inside a site collection, I have multiple subsites.

In each of these subsites I  have created a custom list with associated content type. Here users can create and edit list items. Now using, `SharePoint Search REST API`, i have created an overview(dashboard) of the list items inside these subsites.

One of the columns(`IsCompleted`) inside the content type is of type `Yes/No`. By default, the value is set to **No**. I have mapped it to a `RefinableStringXX`.

My requirement is to show all these list items and whenever a user changes the value of the column to Yes, it should be removed from the webpart.

Now since we are using SharePoint search, it usually takes `15 mins to 1 hour` for the updated value to be reflected in the webpart. But sometimes it takes more than 1 hour. The number of items in the list are also quite less ( < 500 ).

If I **reindex** the site collection, the update is propagated in like 3-5 mins. But it doesn't make sense to reindex it every time a list item is updated.

Has anybody observed such a behaviour ? Is there a better way to deal with problem ?  How do I deal with this delay ?

Answer (score 3):

The only solution to deal with index latency, as long as it's not instant is to query the data directly without using search. But when you have multiple sub-sites, this might not be so pretty client side.

Do you have benchmarks proving hitting re-index index an item quicker compared to just waiting? Afaik Microsoft was talking about kicking off re-index, but at lower priority when that button was clicked - but haven't heard any specifics if it's done or not.

Another solution is to store values in the browser for the current user - and filter using those until search catches up. This at least works in some scenarios when only one person is affected by the results.

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer. I dont have benchmarks at the moment but will update it when i get it. Unfortunately as since we have multiple subsites(could increase in future), directly querying data source is not possible. What i am thinking is to make one Search REST call which gives me 10 items(will limit this) and then for each of these items make separate REST call direct to the source to check for updated values and then managing them in client side. Not pretty at all , but this is the best i can think of since Azure is out of the question :( .

Answer (score 2):

Since you need results as soon as an item is added, and can't wait for the indexing process, how about a remote event handler? Or, perhaps go the new route and set up a [web hook](https://dev.office.com/sharepoint/docs/apis/webhooks/sharepoint-webhooks-using-azure-functions). You could create an Azure function, and configure the web hook to call it for each change from every list. You could write the data that the web part needs to either a centralized SharePoint list, an Azure Table, or an Azure SQL Database, and the web part could display the data from that data store.

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer. I was thinking along similar lines as well but unfortunately cant use azure as its out of budget :( (I should have mentioned that in the question) . Having said that, i am fine with delay of upto 1 hour, but sometimes we observed that sometimes it took more 1 hour for the item to be updated so not sure if its tenant specific. Also i dont want it immediately on item added, but want it on item updated only .

Comment: Webhook events are batched and processed at 5 minute intervals for SP lists afaik, and I wouldn't trust a remove event receiver if my life depended on it.. just seems to prone for missed events. Also, hooking this to each list in all subsites might require a lot of work.  A good old wf doing the same might be a better approach.

The bad part is that search is by far the easiest and non-complex solution - except for the latency :(